# Datatable paginator is not displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, paginator

I am making a very simple datatable with JSF 2.0 tag dataTable but for some reason the page paginator is not displayed. Why is that?

```
<p:dataTable var="garbage" value="#{resultsController.allGarbage}" paginator="true" rows="10">          

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Filename" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.filename}" />
             </p:column> 

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Description" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.description}" />  
             </p:column> 

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Upload date" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.uploadDate}" /> 
             </p:column>                
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `p:dataTable` instead of `h:dataTable`.

The pagination only works with the primefaces dataTable and not with the plain jsf dataTable.

Comment: I understand. I am ussing the primefaces paginator as you can see in the code, but it is not being displayed. I dont understand why?

Comment: Is your data displayed? Is it displayed as one page or all on one page? Your code seems correct (I use it the same way).

Comment: If i remove rows="10" it shows all data, but if i leave it it only shows 10. The data is correctly being displayed correctly but for some weird reason i dont see the paginator.

Answer (score 1):

The `paginatorAlwaysVisible` is an attribute of the primefaces datatable implementation, so you would have to use the datatable tag from the primefaces namespace: `p:dataTable`.

**Edit:** Also, you need a `h:head` element defined in your page, so that the jsf impl knows where to output additional scripts and stylesheets. If that is the case you should be seeing an error message like:

> One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.

To help debuging you could add the following context parameter to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

@sfrj: You probably need something like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="garbage" value="#{resultsController.allGarbage}" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PageLinks} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
```

`paginator="true"` only tells the p:dataTable component that you want the paginator control but you haven't specified what you want in it yet. Hence, you need the `paginatorTemplate` attribute. The `paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"` attribute is good aesthetically if your query returns no record - in which case, the paginator section won't be shown if there are no record. Else, it's visible if there is at least one record returned from your query.